# Windows OS Message Architecture

Tags: windows

Kindly suggest me a good pointer to learn the windows messaging architecture inside the Windows OS.

A good reference book would also do.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Online MSDN describes this well.

You can start with [About Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=VS.85).aspx), and then proceed to [Using messages and Message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928(v=VS.85).aspx) and [Message reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468869(v=VS.85).aspx) if you need to dive into the details.